# Diff last modifications to a file

Tags: git

I am using this (bash):

```
git diff $(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%H" somefile)^! -- somefile
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

For the most recent changes to a file:

```
git log -p -1 <filename>
```

For all changes to a file:

```
git log -p <filename>
```

or, to get a graphical view:

```
gitk <filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
git log -1 -p somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git log --full-diff -1 -p somefile
```

Comment: I stare at the documentation for a few minutes and I don't understand what `--full-diff` does!

Comment: --full-diff just seems to produce diffs of all the files... not just the specified one...

Comment: Yep you can omit the `--full-diff`

Answer (score 0):

As others suggest (+1 to them):

```
git log -1 -p <filename>
```

or where "n" is number of changes back

```
git log -n -p <filename>
```

...But also if you want to get changes from a file that has changed name use the --follow option:

```
git log --follow -1 -p <filename>
```